# What criteria guarantee that gradient descent tends to a local minimum?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, optimization, numerical-optimization, gradient-descent

Is there a set of criteria that a function $f$ can have so as to ensure that the gradient descent algorithm leads us to a local minimum?

If so, why do such criteria ensure reaching a minimum?

Comment: Are you sure you only want a ***local*** minimum?

Comment: @Joe yes, I am sure.

Comment: I think all of the proofs I have seen were for convergence to global minimum, and they usually assumed that the function was convex and differentiable, with a Lipschitz continuous gradient with constant $L>0$, and that step size was chosen via line search. I'm not sure if that's over kill for convergence to a local minimum.